# Can't publish application in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, publish

I have a very weird problem. In Visual Studio 2013 I working on an application for sorting and renaming files. It is not done yet, but I wanted to show it to some other people on another PC. I have tried almost every menu in every possible context but I simply can't find the publishing wizard or any other tool for that. Normally I should just do a right click on the project and have the option "Publish..." there, right? I have also tried the build menu. All I get is "Build", "Rebuild", "Clean" and "Code analysis". No option for publishing. Maybe I am just stupid and forgot to configure something? It seems like the word "publish" has completely vanished from the whole program. I have seen screenshots and in my VS the option is simply missing. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?
I also tried adding an installer project, but then it just tells me that there was some kind of an error. No further information. Just "an error occured".
Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Did you solve it? I have this problem too...

Comment: Nope, I've given up on that :(

Answer (score 0):

Your application after build is in YourProject\bin\Release\ or YourProject\bin\Debug\ path.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately these seem not to work on the computer I want to use. Since I installed the Awesomium browser plug-in there should be a little more than 52 kB I think... When I tried to run it, the computer said, there would be msvcr120d.dll missing although I already installed the latest vcredist package and .NET framework 4.5 and rebooted multiple times. Any idea on that? Then my problem might be solved for once.